# allやpreloadでメモリにキャッシュできてない？？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql, rails-activerecord

自分の認識では、変数に代入すればメモリにキャッシュされることでSQLが発行しなくなくなるはずなのですが
変数に代入しても普通にSQLが発行していて混乱をきたしています。

以下はわかります

```
irb(main):002:0> users = User.all
User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

ですが、以下でもSQLが発行しているのが謎です。
変数に代入したことでメモリにキャッシュされているはずなのでSQLが発行しないはずです。

```
irb(main):003:0> users
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

preloadも同様です。以下はわかります。

```
irb(main):004:0> users = User.preload(:posts)
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
  Post Load (4.5ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "blogs" WHERE "posts"."user_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11) ORDER BY "blogs"."created_at" DESC
```

ですが、キャッシュしたはずなのに再度SQLが発行しています。

```
irb(main):006:0> users
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
  Blog Load (5.4ms)  SELECT "blogs".* FROM "blogs" WHERE "blogs"."user_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11) ORDER BY "blogs"."created_at" DESC
```

### 質問

変数に代入したのに、変数を実行すると再度SQLが発行されるのは何故ですか？

Comment: 自分の手元のプロジェクトでは再現しなかったですね。。(2回目、変数を参照する際に、特にクエリが実行された様子がない。)

Comment: それがほんとに不思議なんですよね。実を言うと、自分も会社のプロジェクトでrails cしたさいは２回目クエリ発行しないんですよ。でも自分の趣味で作ってるアプリのプロジェクトでrails cすると２回目でもクエリ発行するんですよね